# How to get only function declaration from clang AST?

Tags: c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want AST for my C program and want represent in json format. To do so I used `clang -Xclang -ast-dump=json -fSyntax-only main.c` command. It gave a AST. but the AST contains `typeDecl, Value declaration` etc. along with `function declaration`.

I want only a function declaration form my code in JSON form. How can achieve this?

Here is an alternative `clang-check -ast-dump -ast-dump-filter=main main.c` but this cant give the result in JSON form. and when I execute this got some error messages along with output for this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello from C!");
        return 0;
}
```

```
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "main.c"
No compilation database found in /home/..../src or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
```

Comment: Surprisingly, `clang -Xclang -ast-dump=json -fSyntax-only main.cpp` not giving AST if we have included headers. for `C` program it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a well-known issue connected to the differences between `clang frontend` and `clang driver`. It is even covered in [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#id2).

So, run `clang -### main.c`, copy all `-internal-isystem` and `-internal-externc-isystem` options and add them to the command that you run to get AST.

I hope this information will be helpful!