# Clang Python dies while parsing some files of linux

Tags: python, c, clang, clang++

I am using Clang Python bindings to parse source code automatically, but when it parses some linux files, the process dies with no CPU consumption, no error exception, no response, even I cannot use Ctrl+C to kill the terminal. My code is as follows:

```
index = Index.create()
tu = index.parse(file_path)
next_func(tu)
```

It works well with many source repositories such as Libpng, OpenCV, etc. How it dies while parsing files under the dir `linux-master\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c` for example, `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/anx9805.c`. I run the code step by step and found that the error occured when running `tu = index.parse(file_path)`.

The environment: Windows 10, libclang.dll(6.0) python2.7.

I tried the command `clang -cc1 -fsyntax-only -ast-dump anx9805.c`
It reported that some headfiles were not found and construct its ast like follows:

```
In file included from \linux\linux-master\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c\anx9805.c:28:
In file included from \linux\linux-master\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c/bus.h:4: \linux\linux-master\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c/pad.h:4:10: fatal error: 'subdev/i2c.h' file not found
#include <subdev/i2c.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TranslationUnitDecl 0x13de7f82728 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl 0x13de7f82ca0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x13de7f829c0 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x13de7f82d10 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x13de7f829e0 'unsigned __int128'
...
...
```

However, the process is able to end, I don't know if error occurs in python, why the process in terminal does not response, `try...except...` in my code does not catch the error, and even I cannot kill the process. It is allowed to ignore these error files. Most importantly, I do not want the code running breaks off.

Comment: Can you, please, check if clang 6.0 itself crashes on the same file?

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko I added some details about using command clang to parse the file.

Comment: `clang -cc1` doesn't use any of standard include paths. Check out this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050018/how-to-get-only-function-declaration-from-clang-ast/59054621#59054621
How do you provide clang with include directories and macro definitions (required for proper parsing)?

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko In fact, I need to parse many reposities automatically, and include directories and macro definitions are not promised, so I do not set any parse args in python code ```index.parse(file_path)```. It doesn't matter if there are some errors. But I do not hope my code breaks off. I use ```try...except``` to skip errors but it does not work.

Comment: OK, at least try running clang 6.0 with the same include directories (the standard ones) as your code. `-cc1` prevents clang from using them. Let's simply check whether clang in absolutely the same context as libclang crashes or not.

Comment: @ValeriySavchenkoV Thank you for paying attention for this question, finally, I decided to use func_timeout to limit the running time, and skip the dead process.

Comment: Alright, I would still suggest not to ignore errors and timeouts without a clear understanding of why this is happening, otherwise, you won't understand the results as well. But, hey, it's your choice. If you are happy with this solution - go ahead.